# How to find address that holds the balance in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, balance

I am unable to find the address that holds my balance in Bitcoin Core. All receiving addresses has a balance of 0. But there is a balance in the wallet. How do I find the address that holds that balance?

Comment: I think you have used the different address, the Bitcoin-core use more private key and for protecting the privacy of the user

Answer (score 3):

The `listunspent` RPC command will provide a list of all unspent outputs in your wallet, along with the addresses.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for.